# MIPS Initializing array in a loop

Tags: mips

So I'm trying to put 10 numbers that are between 0-50 into an array.

```
    li  $t0, 0      #loopcounter = 0
    la  $a0, array
    addi    $a0, $0, 0  #initialize array index = 0
    loop:
            li  $v0, 5
            syscall
            blt $v0, 0, loop
            bgt $v0, 50, loop
            add $t0, $t0, 1   #increment loop counter

            sw  $a0, 0($a0)     # ERROR HERE #store value of $v0 at index 0
            addi    $a0, $a0, 4     # Increment the index by 4


            blt $t0, 10, loop
```

How would I go about putting those 10 numbers into my array at $a0 and then be able to access them later?

Comment: See the [MIPS instruction set](http://www.mrc.uidaho.edu/mrc/people/jff/digital/MIPSir.html). Specifically the `SW` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will

```
addi $a0, $0, $0     # initialize index with 0
sw $v0, 0($a0)       # store value of $v0 at index 0
addi $a0, $a0, 4     # Increment the index by 4
sw $v0, 0($a0)       # store value of $v0 at index 1

and so on...
```

I left the loop part for you.

Why increment by 4 ?

Becuase integers in MIPS takes up 32 bits or 4 bytes